# Is it possible to build a web-service which is immune to DOSes?

Tags: web-application, denial-of-service

I heard that a service I'm using on the web has some problems with denial of service -attacks. I was wondering if it is theoretically possible to build a web-services where user can send data and which is immune to DOSes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DoS is exactly what "user can send data" means; how do you tell between a legitimate user and someone/something that emulates a legitimate user just to cause trouble ? Often you can't.

For bandwidth-exhaustion attacks the mitigation is simple, you need to have more bandwidth than the attacker; either by doing it yourself or relying on a provider that sits between the Internet and your servers and has more bandwidth than most (all ?) attackers can have. Cloudflare is an example.

For application-level attacks, the ones that try to crash/slow down your server by overloading is more difficult to mitigate; if it's a web application you could use caching to avoid processing the page on each request and instead returning a cached version; you could also limit the number of requests per second to what is reasonable for normal use of your service, another idea is to put resource-intensive pages behind authentication so that only your legitimate customers can access them but outside attackers would just get a 403 without causing the server to process whatever that page was supposed to display - of course the solution isn't perfect either, as a legitimate user may have his account compromised to perform the attack, or that you made that "legitimate" user sad and he's now angry at you and wants revenge (I've seen that happen on video game communities sadly full of script kiddies).